# Error Message when Running Windows 8 Set Up to Fail

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, dell-latitude

I am trying to help my sister install Windows 8 to her laptop, (a Dell Latitude D620), and get rid of Windows 7 Professional. I myself installed Windows 8 to my personal notebook, (Toshiba NB255), which worked out fine. I used winRAR to extract the iso to a folder and ran `setup.exe`. I then get the following error message.

```
C:\Users\{User}\Downloads\92009.16384.WIN8_RTM.12075-1247_X86FRE_ENTERPRISE_EVAL_EN-US-HRM_CENA_X86FREE_EN-US_DV5\Sources\SPWIZENG.DLL 
is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. 
Try installing the program again using the original installation 
media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.
```

I click `ok` and the window shows in the taskbar, so I click it and the following error message appears:

```
The file 'autorun.dll' could not be loaded or is corrupt. Setup cannot continue.
Error code is [0xC1]
```

I click `ok`. The application closes and does nothing else. I figured this is because her computer needed to read the original iso on a disk, but I could not find any re-writable disk in the house to burn it on. I have no flash drive to do it on either. I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing or what.

Comment: Windows _ENTERPRISE_ is a corporate version. Unless your sister also works at the same place you are likely using a pirated version and will not get any help from this site.

Comment: @Hennes he downlaod the legal 90day trial (ENTERPRISE_EVAL)

Answer (score 1):

Redownload the ISO, it was either incomplete or corrupt.